# Can Cloudflare's DNS service (1.1.1.1) result in suboptimal address resolution?

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

Could using Cloudflare's DNS service 1.1.1.1 in some circumstances result in suboptimal server address resolution?

Using something like the extended test on https://www.dnsleaktest.com/results.html when I have my resolvers set to 1.1.1.1 I get results that look like the following:

[dns leak results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6kSr.png)

Note that all of the resolvers (for me in my given physical location & set up) are in Ireland according to this tool.

Much has been said and written about the blazingly fast speed offered by the 1.1.1.1 service with it being hailed as the world's fasted. I don't dispute this, no doubt the resolution is extremely fast. However, once the DNS has done it's job and given me an A record (for example) I'm now at the mercy of the network route to the resolved record.

I am based in London. Does this mean that in some circumstances that the resolvers (when performing geo-based resolution) are more likely to resolves servers in Ireland for example, than those based in London (to which I might have a faster/slightly lower latency/more direct network route). When using my default DNS settings my resolvers are based in London.

My thought is that I might now have a blazingly fast resolver, only to then suffer many orders of magnitude more when actually communicating with the resolved host.

Is this a valid concern or am I overlooking an important detail?

Footnote; I'm interested in a mostly theoretical capacity. I probably don't notice or care much for a few extra ms here of there on a network hop. I'm not a low latency trading bot, I probably wouldn't ever know the difference at a human level.

Comment: This is a valid concern. Your ISP DNS servers may point to caching servers on their network, or say a [Netflix Openconnect](https://openconnect.netflix.com/en_gb/) service they host. Using a different DNS server you may resolve to non-optimal server.

Comment: I don't think Openconnect relies on DNS to choose a server, and as an ISP tech I'd be wary of messing with DNS entries for anything we weren't actually authoritative for. There may be some merit to the idea that geo based services might return an address closer to the Cleanflare DNS server than you. It's hard to gauge how much of a real issue that is though considering their DNS service is likely just as well spread globally as the service you're trying to access in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am based in London. Does this mean that in some circumstances that the resolvers (when performing geo-based resolution) are more likely to resolves servers in Ireland for example, than those based in London (to which I might have a faster/slightly lower latency/more direct network route). When using my default DNS settings my resolvers are based in London.

The short answer is "yes, it can happen".

The longer answer is that it depends on the level of regional granularity provided both by the DNS servers you use *and* the services you consume. The DNS server closest to you geographically will *usually* be the one provided to you by the ISP, but there will always be exceptions. (weird anycast configs interacting with fringe markets, etc.)

There are many considerations that effect whether or not using DNS servers that are physically closest will provide a benefit:

- If the IP address you get from DNS is Anycast enabled, the DNS based exercise is somewhat beside the point. That IP will take you to whatever the network considers closest.
- Assuming that the IP that you get is *not* Anycast enabled, you will only see a difference if you are consuming services that operate geolocation enabled DNS servers. (usually CDNs and such)
- Services that use DNS for this purpose but only do coarse *continental* differentiation usually won't be impacted. As as an example, Ireland and London should both direct you to a EU cluster over a US cluster.
- If a service that you consume offers services in London *and* Ireland, and you use DNS servers located in Ireland, you will take the performance hit.
- If you use DNS servers in Ireland, and the service you consume doesn't have a presence in Ireland, you will more likely than not end up consuming services that are located in a mainland datacenter anyway.
- *Regardless of where the DNS servers physically reside*, the [EDNS0 Client Subnet option](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7871) may get you to the closest services regardless. It requires both the recursive DNS servers you use *and* the authoritative DNS servers to both support the feature.